rotate around does not work inside a pgfshape background path
I am writing a tikz library to draw MLT-DTL-38999 standard connectors. You can find the spec here. http://everyspec.com/MIL-SPECS/MIL-SPECS-MIL-DTL/MIL-DTL-38999L_11330/ Those connectors have "polarisation" keys that only allow mating in a single angular position. My strategy to draw those polarisation keys is the following:

Calculate the points that constitute the "main" key. This key lies on the vertical axis.
Calculate the points that constitute the "secondary" keys on the vertical axis. And rotate them in position using something like

 \begin{scope}[rotate around={\keyAngle:(0,0)}]
     %Drawing lines and arcs here
 \end{scope}

But the rotate around option seems to have no effect. Here is the code:
\makeatletter

% Define a custom shape for the MLT-DTL-38999 connector
\pgfdeclareshape{dtlConnector}{
    % page 91 of the standard. Inner and outer diameters from page 78

    % Inherit properties from a circle
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}

    % Define keys option (default to false)
    \saveddimen{\keysize}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/dtlConnector/keysize}}
    \pgfkeys{/dtlConnector/.cd,
        draw keys/.store in=\drawkeys, draw keys=false,
        keysize/.initial=0.5cm % Size of the keys
    }

    % Define the drawing routine
    \backgroundpath{
        % For shell size 15
        \def \innerCircle {20.63}
        \def \outerCircle {22.84}
        \def \mainKWayWidth {3.2}


        % Calculate start and end angles of the outer arc. We find this by
        % calculating the angle required for a line emanating from the center
        % of the circle to intersect the circle at \mainKWayWidth/2. This is
        % simple trigonometry. The result is in degrees and the sign for now
        % does not matter.
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\outerang}{
            asin(\mainKWayWidth/\outerCircle)
        }

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\innerang}{
            asin(\mainKWayWidth/\innerCircle)
        }

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\innerstartang}{
            90 + (\innerang)
        }

        %Because tikz positive direction is counter clockwise continue from
        % \innerstartang until we have reached the correct point. This required
        % some trial and error reach number 450
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\innerendang}{
            450 - (\innerang)
        }

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\spx}{
            cos(\innerstartang)*\innerCircle/2
        }

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\spy}{
            sin(\innerstartang)*\innerCircle/2
        }


        \draw  (\spx, \spy) arc (\innerstartang:\innerendang:\innerCircle/2);


        % The angles required to draw outer arc of the main key
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\startang}{
            90 - (\outerang)
        }

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\endang}{
            90 + (\outerang)
        }


        %mkas --> main key arc start
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmkas}{
            \mainKWayWidth/2
        }
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymkas}{
            (\outerCircle/2) * cos(\outerang)
        }

        \draw (\xmkas, \ymkas) arc (\startang:\endang:\outerCircle/2 );


        % Y values for vertical line segments
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\outery}{
            cos(\outerang)*\outerCircle/2
        }

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\innery}{
            cos(\innerang)*\innerCircle/2
        }

        \draw (-\mainKWayWidth/2,\innery)  -- (-\mainKWayWidth/2, \outery);
        \draw (\mainKWayWidth/2,\innery)  -- (\mainKWayWidth/2, \outery);

        % Draw the secondary keyways.
        \foreach \keyAngle in { 60, 120} {

            \def \keywayWidth{1.6}

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\outerang}{
                asin(\keywayWidth/\outerCircle)
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\innerang}{
                asin(\keywayWidth/\innerCircle)
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\innerstartang}{
                90 + (\innerang)
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\innerendang}{
                450 - (\innerang)
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\spx}{
                cos(\innerstartang)*\innerCircle/2
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\spy}{
                sin(\innerstartang)*\innerCircle/2
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\startang}{
                90 - (\outerang)
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\endang}{
                90 + (\outerang)
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmkas}{
                -\keywayWidth/2
            }
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymkas}{
                (\outerCircle/2) * cos(\outerang)
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\outery}{
                cos(\outerang)*\outerCircle/2
            }

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\innery}{
                cos(\innerang)*\innerCircle/2
            }

            % Rotate the entire coordinate system
            \begin{scope}[rotate around={\keyAngle:(0,0)}]
                \draw (\keywayWidth/2, \ymkas) arc (\startang:\endang:\outerCircle/2);
                \draw (-\keywayWidth/2, \innery) -- (-\keywayWidth/2, \outery);
                \draw (\keywayWidth/2, \innery) -- (\keywayWidth/2, \outery);
            \end{scope}

        }

    }
}

\makeatother % changes the catcode of @ character to 12


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[dtlConnector] (connector) at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

The result that I get is the following: 
